# Inequalities and modulus

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If two numbers are less than a given number, how can we algebraically show that their difference is also less than the given number . 
Both numbers are greater than zero and in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You have $2<3$, $-2<3$ but the difference is $2-(-2)=4 >3$

Comment: @gammatester The OP requires the numbers to be greater than zero.

Comment: I imagine originally it wasn't stated that they had to be positive.  By the way.  They don't need to be rational.  The result/proof doesn't require it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb Q^+$, such that $x < z$, $y< z$. WLOG, suppose $x \leq y$.

As $x$ is positive, $y-x \leq y$ (because $y - (y-x) = x \geq 0$), and $y< z$. By transitivity, $y-x < z$.

Comment: Thanx.....what a coincidence.....it came to me at the exact same time ! Love math!

Comment: You don't need to WLOG x < y.  both y - x and x - y are less than z for the same reason. But if you *do* wlog you shold consider the case if x = y. And if x > 0 the $y - x < y$ is a stronger statement than $y -x \le y$.

Comment: @fleablood: thanks, I edited. Indeed, both $x-y$ and $y-x$ are less than $z$, but one of them is negative, thus boring.

Comment: @fleablood What is wlog?

Comment: Without Loss Of Generality.  It's shorthand for noting that when various options are equivalent we can validly make assumptions that will not effect the results but will simplify the explanation.  In this example:  The difference between x and y is either y - x if y> x or it is x -y if x > y or it is 0 if x = y. So we have to do three cases... NOT! .. we can assume WITHOUT LOSS OF GENERALITY that x $\le$ y because one must be larger or equal than the other than the variables are just lables and we'd just do the exact same argument a second time and ... well WLOG!

Comment: ... although it's a good idea to be wary of WLOGing.  One really *does* need to be sure that the assumption *is* general.  But it can be powerful.  For example:  "prove $a*b*c \le (\frac{a+b+c}3) ^3$" you will need to compare min(a,b,c) to max(a,b,c) and refer to the middle value of a,b, or c.  It's easier to assume $a \le b \le c$.  But can we? or do we need to do six separate cases?  well, we can as they have to be ordered *some* way and as addition and multiplication is commutative and variable are labels it doesn't matter which order we choose.

Comment: @fleablood Thanx a lot!!.....vocabulary increase !

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample (only 1) giving so take $a=-7,b=-200,c=-5$ now take difference $a-b=-7+200>c$ also you can get eg where $a-b,b-a>c$